# find a regexpression that matches word boundaries that include accented letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression to use in preg_match that will catch words like cialis when as a word with spaces and also as a word with a tag up close ie     `<b>cialis</b>`, so I used this

```
$word = "cialis";
if (preg_match_all("/\b$word\b/i", $content, $matches)) {
        $caught[] = $matches[0];
    }
```

Which worked great and didn't fire with words like specialist that have cialis in them. All was fine until I hit some french words such as spécialisé
The é is treated as if its a word boundary and so spécialisé gets caught. What regex would stop spécialisé being added to $caught?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use modifier `u` for unicode strings :

```
/\b$word\b/iu
```

Comment: @Phil Well, so you can tell this to community by vote and accepting the answer! ;)